# Retrieving biggest decimal value from a local .mdf Database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created a very simple SQL Server database called `Personnel.mdf` in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. In this database, I have a table called `Employee` with this definition:

[Employee Table Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1crO.png)

Now, I'm trying to get the highest hourly pay rate and have it output in a message on a form I have created. I created a ADO.NET Entity Data Model of the `Personnel` database in my project and using an instance of that at the moment.

Anyone have any ideas how I could do this? Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(HourlyPayRate) from EMPLOYEE`

Answer (score 0):

With Entity Framework and Linq-to-Entities, try something like this:

```
// using your database context - adapt to your DbContext class!
using (testEntities ctx = new testEntities())
{
    // sort employees descending by hourly pay rate - take the first 
    Employee highestPaidEmployee = ctx.Employee.OrderByDescending(e => e.HourlyPayRate)
                                               .FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine("Your highest paid emplyoee is: {0} with an hourly pay rate of {1}", highestPaidEmployee.Name, highestPaidEmployee.HourlyPayRate);
}
```